# Max number of thread in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a list of `objects1` and each `object1` contains an list of `objects2` and each `object2` contains a list of values.

My code is this:

```
for object1 in object1_list:
   for object2 in object1.object2_list:
       for value in object2:
          # do something
```

I am running with multi-threading, in particular I created a thread for each object1 in the list.

The problem is that some `objects1` have a bigger list, so I was thinking to create also a thread for each `object2`. The lists are very large (million of elements), so in this way i will create millions of threads. Is it a good solution or can i do better?

Answer (score 0):

You can create as many threads as you like, but your cpu can only handle so many threads at a time. I would not recommend creating millions of threads, it will be more efficient if you only create a few threads doing some part of the task.

Comment: Yes, my point was that at the end the biggest object1 will run only with a thread with my solution (one thread for each object1). So, I would improve it.